# How do I find the index of a known value in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using the describe() function I have noted the max value, 1350 in this case, that is present in my column 'LOCALGBUSED', but as my dataframe contains millions of rows, how do I find the index that holds that value?

```
count    3483638.000000
mean         149.145475
std          206.053277
min            0.000000
25%            6.000000
50%           80.000000
75%          200.000000
max         1350.000000
Name: LOCALGBUSED, dtype: object
```

I tried using this code to get the index of the max value of that column rather then the value itself, but the index it displayed did not contain the listed max value of 1350

```
column = data['LOCALGBUSED']
max_index = column.idxmax()
print(max_index)

index # from code above
print(data.iloc[397386])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`idxmax` returns the index, so you need `loc`, not `iloc`:

```
data.loc[data['LOCALGBUSED'].idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 1):

`.iloc` should Just use `.idxmax()` with `.loc`:

```
data.loc[data['LOCALGBUSED'].idxmax()]
```